# How do I turn off keyboard shortcuts in Yahoo! Mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a big problem with writing mail in Polish because all diacritic symbols are achieved by right <kbd>alt</kbd>+letter and this interferes with Yahoo shortcuts.

Is there a more convenient way than editing the mail somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not with Yahoo Mail Shortcut as it has no keyboard shortcut as right alt + letter (check [Yahoo Mail keyboard Shortcuts](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail-for-desktop/SLN3578.html?impressions=true)), instead the problem is with your browser's keyboard shortcuts. So try disabling/configuring those or consider using a different browser.

For Google Chrome [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf?hl=en-US) may be helpful.

Comment: I use firefox. Anyway I can edit message in gmail and R_ALT + L does not close my current message while on yahoo does

Comment: @teodozjan - Can you please specify which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: 35.0 but now something has changed. Only R_ALT+Z works as CTRL+Z while other keys are served as expected